# I want to identify the data in an interval of time between two days

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, the first is the data table about the stock price per minute. It is composed of six columns, the date and time, the opening price, the highest price, the lowest price, and the closing price.

Table Data

```
ID  Field1      Field2       Field3   Field4    Field5   Field6
2   2016.02.17  11:36:00 PM  1.42918  1.42924   1.42904  1.4292
3   2016.02.17  11:37:00 PM  1.42919  1.42922   1.42886  1.42912
4   2016.02.17  11:38:00 PM  1.42911  1.42917   1.42902  1.42917
5   2016.02.17  11:39:00 PM  1.42918  1.42918   1.42887  1.42904
```

The second table consists of seven columns, the date and six different times.

Table Time

```
ID  Field1      Field2      Field3      Field4       Field5      Field6      Field7
2   2016.01.02  5:35:00 AM  6:58:00 AM  12:25:00 PM  3:30:00 PM  5:52:00 PM  7:22:00 PM
3   2016.01.03  5:35:00 AM  6:58:00 AM  12:25:00 PM  3:30:00 PM  5:53:00 PM  7:22:00 PM
4   2016.01.04  5:36:00 AM  6:59:00 AM  12:26:00 PM  3:31:00 PM  5:53:00 PM  7:23:00 PM
5   2016.01.05  5:36:00 AM  6:59:00 AM  12:26:00 PM  3:31:00 PM  5:54:00 PM  7:24:00 PM
```

I do the work of four queries to get the stock price in a specified period from the second table showing the date, the opening price, the highest price and its time of achievement, the lowest price and time and its time of achievement, and the closing price.

Queries 1

```
SELECT
  First(Times.Field1) AS [Date], First(Times.Field2) AS FirstOfField2, 
  First(Times.Field6) AS FirstOfField6, First(Data.Field3) AS [Open],   
  Max(Data.Field4) AS [Max], Min(Data.Field5) AS [Min], Last(Data.Field6) AS [Close]
FROM Data, Times
WHERE (
  ((Data.Field1)=[Times].[Field1])
  AND ((Data.Field2) Between [Times].[Field2] And [Times].[Field6])
)
GROUP BY Times.ID;
```

Result 1

```
Date        FirstOfField2  FirstOfField6  Open     Max      Min      Close
2016.02.19  5:29:00 AM     6:22:00 PM     1.43217  1.4337   1.42461  1.42653
2016.02.22  5:28:00 AM     6:23:00 PM     1.42744  1.42892  1.40567  1.41282
2016.02.23  5:27:00 AM     6:24:00 PM     1.4133   1.41527  1.40615  1.40813
```

Queries 2

```
SELECT
  First(Result.Date) AS [Date], First(Data.Field2) AS MaxTime, 
  First(Result.Max) AS MaxValue
FROM Data, Result
WHERE (
  ((Data.Field4)=[Result].[Max])
  AND ((Data.Field1)=[Result].[Date])
  AND ((Data.Field2) Between [Result].[FirstOfField2] And [Result].[FirstOfField6])
)
GROUP BY Result.Date;
```

Result 2

```
Date          MaxTime     MaxValue
2016.02.18  3:21:00 PM  1.43938
2016.02.19  8:39:00 AM  1.4337
2016.02.22  8:37:00 AM  1.42892
```

Queries 3

```
SELECT
  First(Result.Date) AS [Date], First(Data.Field2) AS MinTime, 
  First(Result.Min) AS MinValue
FROM Data, Result
WHERE (
  ((Data.Field5)=[Result].[Min])
  AND ((Data.Field1)=[Result].[Date])
  AND ((Data.Field2) Between [Result].[FirstOfField2] And [Result].[FirstOfField6])
)
GROUP BY Result.Date;
```

Result 3

```
Date          MinTime      MinValue
2016.02.18  10:01:00 AM  1.42558
2016.02.19  4:32:00 PM   1.42461
2016.02.22  3:40:00 PM   1.40567`
```

Queries 4 (Final)

```
SELECT
  First(Result.Date) AS [Date], First(Result.FirstOfField2) AS FirstOfFirstOfField2,
  First(Result.FirstOfField6) AS FirstOfFirstOfField6, First(Result.Open) AS [Open],
  First(Result.Max) AS MaxValue, First(Max.MaxTime) AS MaxTime, First(Result.Min) AS MinValue,
  First(Min.MinTime) AS MinTime, First(Result.Close) AS [Close]
FROM Result, [Max], [Min]
WHERE (((Result.Max)=([Max].[MaxValue])) AND ((Result.Min)=([Min].[MinValue])))
GROUP BY Result.Date;
```

Result 4 (Final)

```
Date        FirstOfFirstOfField2  FirstOfFirstOfField6  Open     MaxValue  MaxTime      MinValue  MinTime      Close
2016.02.18  5:30:00 AM            6:22:00 PM            1.42989  1.43938   3:21:00 PM   1.42558   10:01:00 AM  1.43572
2016.02.19  5:29:00 AM            6:22:00 PM            1.43217  1.4337    8:39:00 AM   1.42461   4:32:00 PM   1.42653
2016.02.22  5:28:00 AM            6:23:00 PM            1.42744  1.42892   8:37:00 AM   1.40567   3:40:00 PM   1.41282
2016.02.23  5:27:00 AM            6:24:00 PM            1.4133   1.41527   11:41:00 AM  1.40615   5:47:00 PM   1.40813
```

The problem that I am facing, when I want to identify two different times between two different dates.

Answer (score 0):

Group by both date and time. If you also want by ID then group by id, date and time

Comment: Example: when I need to analyze the data in an interval of time between 11:00 pm on 17.02.2016 and 05:00 am on 18.02.2016